# Python/PySpark - Upload large pandas dataframe > 5GB to s3

Tags: python, dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I need some inputs on how to upload large dataframe that is greater than 5GB that holds csv data to s3 using python.

I'm running a glue job (PYSPARK) that concats several csv files into one single csv and uploads the concatenated csv to s3

I'm getting the error "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (EntityTooLarge) when calling the UploadPart operation: Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size"

Below is what I'm trying to do:

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(obj["Body"], delimiter=",", keep_default_na=False, low_memory=False, dtype=str)
dataframe.to_csv(buffer_value, sep=",", index=False)
payload = buffer_value.getvalue()

client_kwargs = {'S3.Client.create_multipart_upload': {'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms', 'SSEKMSKeyId': kms_key}, 'S3.Client.put_object': {'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms', 'SSEKMSKeyId': kms_key}}

with smart_open.open(url, 'w', transport_params={'client_kwargs': client_kwargs, 'client': s3_client}) as payload_write:
    payload_write.write(payload)
```

Comment: Looked into `boto3`'s `upload_file` method?

Answer (score -2):

This bit of code worked for me. The key is to convert the payload into BytesIO.

```
            buffer = BytesIO(payload.getvalue().encode())
            s3_client.upload_fileobj(
                buffer, 
                bucket,
                file_name,
                ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", "SSEKMSKeyId": kms_key})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).